# Aggregating timestamps spanning multiple days in Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am new to pandas and I am trying to plot the number of events in function of time, *at different time resolutions*.

My data file looks like this:

```
223789 213163 1341100972
223789 213163 1341100972
376989 50329 1341101181
26375 168366 1341101183
376989 13813 1341101192
...
```

The third column is the timestamp. I want to read the file and plot the number of rows per timestamp. This is what I do:

```
data = read_table(file_name, sep=' ', header=None, names=['u1','u2','timestamp'], dtype={'timestamp': np.int}, parse_dates=[2], date_parser=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)
data.groupby('timestamp').size().plot()
```

This works if I am fine with a resolution of *seconds*, but I don't understand what is the best way to aggregate the data to obtain a resolution of minutes or hours. In fact if I do:

```
data.groupby(data['timestamp'].map(lambda t: t.hour)).size().plot()
```

the problem is that all the rows referring to the same hour *in different days* are aggregated, whereas I would like to keep the time ordering.

I haven't found a solution browsing related posts and Stack Overflow questions. Could anyone help, please?

Thanks!

Comment: check out the TimeGrouper method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TimeGrouper method, you could do this

`data.set_index('timestamp').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1D')).count()`

First `set_index` to `timestamp`, then `groupby` over a day period `1D`

Similarly, for minutes

`data.set_index('timestamp').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('60s')).count()`

and hours resolution at

`data.set_index('timestamp').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1H')).count()`